# Sandboxed iFrame in Chrome Extension -- Dynamically set 'src' attribute?

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension

## Question

In my Chrome Extension, how can I dynamically change the `src` of an iFrame displayed in an html page in the chrome side panel?

### Details

I want to load a web site that I control in the side panel and communicate with it and my extension code. Google requires remotely-loaded code be in a sandbox, so I have created one, `sandbox.html` that is used in the iframe as `<iframe src="sandbox.html" />`. This works, but the problem I have is that I want to set the `src` attribute for different environments, prod, stage, test, etc, and I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

### Ideas

1. Create a SidePanel.html page for each environment where there's an iFrame in it whose `src` attribute set to the given environment url I want.
2. Have one SidePanel.html file that has an iframe that is always `sandbox.html`, and have code within the sandox set the document like:

   `window.location.replace('https://prod.mysite.com');`

For #1, I don't like the duplication, so I'm leaning towards the, as yet, untested #2. Even if #2 works, I don't know if the Google Review gods would approve that.

### Final Thoughts

I'm sure this is a common issue with chrome extension development. What have others done?

Thanks!

Comment: #2 will work as there's nothing in the rules against embedding an external site. I don't see why you can't just change elem.src in js that runs in sidepanel.html though.

Comment: I honestly don't know if I can or not, @wOxxOm. Technically, I can, but would Google's Reviewers be okay with dynamically changing the iframe's src? I assume I'd need to manage that within a sandboxed page in my extension, so the `src` would have to stay as `sandbox.html`.

Comment: There was never anything against iframes in their policy, which is why I wonder why you think it's problematic.